# How to change the border of CircleMarker in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I'm using  Leaflet 1.3.4 and I want to change the border of CircleMarker (make it bigger).
I created it in this way:

```
      var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 25,
        fillColor: "#24D238",// "#28ea3f",//"#0163FF",
        color: "#A9F6B2", //"#0163FF",
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        // className: 'marker-cluster'

      };


      geoJson = new L.geoJson(buildingPoints, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
          return new L.circleMarker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng], geojsonMarkerOptions).bindTooltip('53', { className: 'text', direction: 'center', permanent: true, interactive: true });//{color:"#0163FF", radius: feature.properties.radius});
        },
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        }
      }).addTo(map)
```

I know how to do it via `DivIcon`, but I need to use CircleMarker.
I can't find any border param in leaflet.css corresponds to CircleMarker.

I've tried specifying `className` in options, but it doesn't help (even if I use SVG renderer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [the `weight` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#path-weight), which is literally «the width of the stroke in pixels».

Comment: [@IvanSanchez](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/53755/ivansanchez), it was really a piece of cake, thank you for a hint!

Answer (score 2):

In leaflet circleMarker function have fix radius with any zoom if you want change radius circle use `{radius: 50.4}`  or if want change weight border circle use `{weight:12}` like this  https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/6btw7zg8/5/

[image]

Comment: sorry,I edit answer